Permesso di soggiorno expired 2 years ago
My permesso di soggiorno is expired way back 2 years ago in my home country in October 2021 I came to Pakistan in 2020, because of coronavirus I have lost my work totally, that's why I in frustration I left everything Ang come back to Pakistan, I was there in Italy since 2011 and got the immigration of 2012,I have  identity card valid until 2029,can I get back to Italy .if I can than what's the process please help me out

AFAIK your ID card only proves your identity and cannot be used as a valid document to travel to Italy unless you also have a valid residence permit. Does the back of your ID card say “non valida per l’espatrio”?

Yes I know I m just asking that can I get permission for re entry in Italy.or is there any procedure to re take my permesso di soggiorno

If you meet the criteria, you can apply for a re-entry visa in Pakistan. After the application has been submitted, the visa office needs to be authorised from the Questura (Police station) which originally issued the permesso di soggiorno. The visa is issued only after the relevant Questura releases the necessary authorisation. The visa processing time starts when the authorisation is received and all documents are provided.
However, according to this source, you may be outside the timeframe for a re-entry visa. I recommend contacting your local Italian Consulate for advice.
